# cx_oracle insert with select query not working

Tags: python-2.7, insert, cx-oracle

I am trying to insert in database(Oracle) in python with cx_oracle. I need to select from table and insert into another table.

```
 insert_select_string = "INSERT  INTO wf_measure_details(PARENT_JOB_ID,  STAGE_JOB_ID,  MEASURE_VALS,  STEP_LEVEL,  OOZIE_JOB_ID,  CREATE_TIME_TS) \
                               select PARENT_JOB_ID,  STAGE_JOB_ID,  MEASURE_VALS,  STEP_LEVEL,  OOZIE_JOB_ID,  CREATE_TIME_TS from wf_measure_details_stag where oozie_job_id = '{0}'.format(self.DAG_id)"

 conn.executemany(insert_select_string)
 conn.commit()
 insert_count = conn.rowcount
```

But I am getting below error. I do not have select parameter of data as data is getting from select query.

```
Required argument 'parameters' (pos 2) not found
```

Please suggest how to solve this

Comment: Start by reading the manual https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html and looking at examples.  Do not use '{0}'.format(self.DAG_id) because it is a security risk and performance problem.  The executemany() method is only called when you are passing in multiple binds values as data from Python - which you are not.

Comment: @ChristopherJones I wrote format because I don't know how to bind variables in insert statement where values are taking from select command. The document link which you shared do not have such example of insert + select.

Comment: Look a little lower: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#insert-and-update-statements. It doesn't make any difference whether you use a simple insert statement or an insert with a select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Chris in the comments to your question, you want to use cursor.execute() instead of cursor.executemany(). You also want to use bind variables instead of interpolated parameters in order to improve performance and reduce security risks. Take a look at the [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#insert-and-update-statements). In your case you would want something like this (untested):

```
cursor.execute("""
        INSERT  INTO wf_measure_details(PARENT_JOB_ID,  STAGE_JOB_ID,
                MEASURE_VALS,  STEP_LEVEL,  OOZIE_JOB_ID,  CREATE_TIME_TS)
        select PARENT_JOB_ID,  STAGE_JOB_ID,  MEASURE_VALS,  STEP_LEVEL,
                OOZIE_JOB_ID,  CREATE_TIME_TS
        from wf_measure_details_stag
        where oozie_job_id = :id""",
        id=self.DAG_id)
```